# Implicit rule skipped by makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a Makefile for compiling some C source files, and put the output in different Build directory, it looks a bit like the makefile below:

```
 OBJDIR=/home/test/alpha
 SRCDIR=/home/test/beta
 # make variable will be exanded when used (and not at declaration)
 OBJECTS:= $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(notdir $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c))))

SOURCES:=$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c))

.PHONY: copySourcesOver linkSources sharedLibrary
 copySourcesOver: $(SOURCES)
 cp $(SOURCES) $(OBJDIR)/

# pattern
$(OBJECTS)/%.o : $(OBJECTS)/%.c
 gcc -fPIC $< -o $@

linkSources: $(OBJECTS)
 gcc -shared -o libshared.so $@

sharedLibrary: copySourcesOver \
 linkSources \
```

So what is happening is that when I run the target:

```
make sharedLibrary
```

I get no rule for making `$(OBJECTS)`. The interesting part is when I make this target a second time I don't get this makefile error, and I get the shared library.

I have done a bit of research and I have found out that Makefile does not expand implicit rules for PHONY targets, that is why I have changed `linkSources` from a PHONY target to a normal file. But unfortunately it does not solve the issue.

I don't see why the pattern is only executed the second time I run `make sharedLibrary`

Comment: Aside from what the answer below points out, your makefile will also break if you use more than one job (`-j`); there's no guarantee that prerequisites are executed in order, if one prerequisite depends on the other then *express this in the makefile*.

Comment: Good point. I will add all dependencies

Comment: Some of your rules don't state their targets as their targets or their dependencies as their dependencies, so `make`'s checking whether a rule must run can't be expected to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make executes in 2 phases. In the first phase it checks what targets are out-of-date and need updating. In the second phase it executes the commands that updates the targets. That means that it checks that the object files are up to date before it actually copies the source files.

So it checks and determines that the object files are up-to-date THEN it copies the (updated) source files to `$(OBJDIR)`.

There is some good reading on this subject [in the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html).

Comment: So what I can conclude after reading the documentation is that: OBJDIR=/home/test/alpha and SRCDIR=/home/test/beta their right sided will have a deferred expansion . The $(OBJECTS) is not expanded at the first run of makefile, only at the second

Comment: The key information is at the bottom, `Rule definition`. The rule `sharedLibrary : copySourcesOver linkSources` is checked immediately. The check for `linkSources` will result in no action, since the files are up-to-date (remember that the updated files haven't been copied yet) while the check for `copySourcesOver` will result in a copy of any updated source files.

Answer (score 1):

Quote:

```
# pattern
$(OBJECTS)/%.o : $(OBJECTS)/%.c
  gcc -fPIC $< -o $@
```

This rule is nonsense since `OBJECTS` is a variable containing multiple words, and not a single path component; moreover, the `.c` sources are not in the same directory as the objects (the whole point of this).

I suspect you want:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
```

The pattern on the left matches any one of the object file patterns you have calculated in `OBJECTS` by rewriting their `$(SRCDIR)` part to `$(OBJDIR)`.

By the way, see how this  pattern rule easily performs the reverse rewrite? The match on the left is converted to  the `.c` prerequisite on the right. See how the rule doesn't use `notdir` or `addprefix`? You could do the same thing (in reverse) when calculating `OBJECTS`. Drop the `notdir` and `addprefix` and transform each path with a single `patsubst`.

Also, I'd eliminate the repeated `wildcard`. Get the `SOURCES` first, and then calculate `OBJECTS` from sources.

**Lastly, how will this work in a fresh checkout, when the object directory doesn't exist? You need some `mkdir -p` in there.**  `gcc ... -o foo/bar.o` will not create the `foo` directory.

Comment: The first target copySourcesOver copies the sources to the object directory. Yes I agree, I have changed it to static pattern rule, $(OBJECTS):%.o:%.c

Comment: Can your Makefile ever run in a situation when the objects  directory doesn't exist at all?

Comment: One question please what is reverse rewrite ?

Comment: "Reverse rewrite" is the opposite of what the rule is doing: the rule matches the  .o pattern on the left against a target, and then rewrites it to the .c prerequisite on the right.   This is reverse in relation to  what you did to calculate the .o OBJECTS from the sources.   Basically the pattern rule is doing  `patsubst(leftpat, rightpat, target)`.

Comment: No, in this case the object directory pre-exists, this is the makefile variable OBJDIR. I see your point, I would do the same in another diff

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you for reviewing and explanation :)